# IOS/Objective-C/Storyboard: Back Button of Pushed View Controller Not Active

Tags: ios, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

I have a VC that pushes another VC onto the stack using code and referencing its Storyboard identifier.  However, for some reason the back button of the newly pushed VC is not working and says "Back" instead of the name of the VC that pushed it as it normally does.

The code in the presenting VC is as follows:

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;

```
IDProfilePicVC *picVC =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addprofile"];
//push using existing nav
[self.navigationController pushViewController:picVC animated:YES];
```

While the code is successfully pushing the new VC onto the stack, the button says "Back" instead of the name of the firstVC and, moreover, is inactive. Nothing happens when you press it.

I use this code elsewhere in the app and it behaves as expected. There is no code in the first or second VC to make the back butten inactive and I am at a loss to understand why this is happening. I also, by the way, set the title in code in viewdidload.

Are there any other settings, for example, in Storyboard that could account for this behavior?  The second VC is embedded in a nav or its own for what it's worth but I am bypassing that nav in this case.

**Edit:**

I deleted the extra nav (in which the secondVC was embedded) and it did not change anything

**Second Edit**

From the first VC, I was able to go to a different VC without any problem.  And when I went from a different VC to the secondVC, I got the non functioning Back button.  This suggests the problem is in some setting of the secondVC.  The secondVC does open, it just has a non-working "Back" for the back button instead of a working back button with the name of the sending VC .

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show more of your code. As well, edit your question to make it easier to understand exactly what's happening. Giving your view controllers actual names instead of vague descriptions (e.g. *first*, *second*, *different*).

Comment: I solved the issue.  There was a back button in storyboard of the second view controller that was hiding/blocking that of the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem and comes here in the future, here is what caused it. I discovered that a back button in storyboard for the destination VC will block the back button that is automatically created by the navigation controller as part of the push.
The back button was not visible on the storyboard, but was present under "Navigation item, Left Bar Button Items" in the outline pane. Deleting it there solved the problem.